# Images lining up weirdly in ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have made a ListBox which has an ItemTemplate that looks like this:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Height="80" Width="80">
                        <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding image.ImageSource}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

And I'm trying to fill the Listbox with Images (as you might have noticed)
It's working just fine with the binding but, the images seem to be lining up in a strange way, even though I have set the Image to be centered inside of the Grid.

Here is an example-image:

[image]

Notice how there is a small blue line on the right side of the image, as if I were to have margin.

I have a fixed height and width for the grid to keep the listbox looking nice.

I achieved the horizontal stack of the items with the following XAML:

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Does anyone know how to make these images centered within the grid?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Aero theme defines a `Padding` of `2,0,0,0` for `ListBoxItems`, so there is space to the left of the content. To get rid of it define your own `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle` and override it.

Something like:

```
<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Padding"
                    Value="0"/>
    </Style>
</ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried HorizontalAlignment tags for the Image?

```
<Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
```

There are also `VerticalAlignment` too if you need it.

If that doesn't work try the ListBox property HostizontalContentAlignment

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
```